# Difficulty solving this linear congruence $2x + 4y \equiv 6 \,\, (mod \,\, 8)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am trying to solve the equivalence:

$2x + 4y \equiv 6 \,\, (mod \,\, 8)$

So far, I have: $4y \equiv -2x + 6 \,\, (mod \,\, 8)$

And I am trying to find the inverse of $4 \,\, mod \,\, 8$, so I can multiply that on both sides of the equation, leaving the coefficient of $y$ to be 1. However, I am struggling to find the inverse of $4 \,\, mod \,\, 8$, since I can't find a number to multiply to 4 that will make it $8x + 1$, since $4$ is even.

Comment: Maybe try solving for $x$.

Comment: Hint: Solve $x + 2y \equiv 3 \pmod 4$

Comment: By the linked dupes $\ 2x\equiv 6-4y\pmod 8\iff x\equiv 3-2y\pmod 4\ \ $

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$ > (2x + 4y) \equiv 6 \pmod{8}$

$a \equiv b \pmod{c} \iff c ~| ~(a - b) ~: ~a,b,c \in \Bbb{Z}, ~c \neq 0$.

Therefore, the problem is converted to :

find all $(x,y) \in \Bbb{Z^2}$ such that $8 ~| ~(2x + 4y - 6).$

However, $8 ~| ~(2x + 4y - 6) \iff 4 ~| ~(x + 2y - 3).$

Therefore, the problem is converted to :

find all $(x,y) \in \Bbb{R^2}$ such that $(x + 2y) \equiv 3 \pmod{4}.$

For such a simple problem, there are a variety of approaches.  My approach is:

$x$ will have form $4m + r$, where $r \in \{0,1,2,3\}.$

$y$ will have form $4n + s$, where $s \in \{0,1,2,3\}.$

Then, $r + 2s \equiv 3\pmod{4} \implies r \equiv 3 - 2s \pmod{4}$.

Clearly, $s \in \{0,2\} \implies r = 3$ 
and $s \in \{1,3\} \implies r = 1.$

Thus, the full set of solutions is :

$\{(x,y) \in \Bbb{Z^2} ~: $
$[x \equiv 1\pmod4 ~\text{and}~ y \equiv 1\pmod4]~~$ or 
$[x \equiv 1\pmod4 ~\text{and}~ y \equiv 3\pmod4]~~$ or 
$[x \equiv 3\pmod4 ~\text{and}~ y \equiv 0\pmod4]~~$ or 
$[x \equiv 3\pmod4 ~\text{and}~ y \equiv 2\pmod4]\}.$

Note that the above specification may be shortened by recognizing that $y$ even if and only $y$ is equivalent to either $0$ or $2, \pmod{4}.$

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque Normally, I would agree with you.  However, once the answer of Wuestenfux was posted, I anticipated that the OP would be confused.  Then, the most effective teaching is to post a contrasting answer directly, rather than referring the poster to a separate mathSE article.  We may have to agree to disagree on this unusual situation.

Answer (score -1):

Here 4 is not invertible mod 8.

Generally, an integer $a$ is invertible mod $n$ if and only if $\gcd(a,n)=1$.

In $2(x+2y)\equiv 2\cdot 3\mod 8$ one cannot use the shortening rule, which would lead to
$x+2y\equiv 3\mod 8$ (shortening by 2), since 2 is a zero-divisor mod 8 which means that $2\cdot 4=0 \mod 8$.

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this without using inverses?

Comment: 2 is also not invertible mod 8.

Comment: Understood, but is there a way to solve this without using inverses?

Comment: Shortening also doesnt work, see my post.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).